# What is difference between spark.jars and spark.driver.extraClassPath

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop2

I'm trying to run spark program using spark-submit in yarn-client mode and getting classNotFound Exception. So my question is in which parameter should I pass my jar(--jars or --driver-class-path).

Spark =2.0.0
HDP 2.5
Hadoop= 2.7.3

Comment: agree everything is pretty much answered in that post - in particular --jars does *not* add things to the classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--jars` if you want to make these jars available to both driver and executor class-paths. If the required jar is only to be used by driver code, use option `--driver-class-path`